# Spring Boot project not resolving placeholder variable when restarting with @reboot

Tags: spring-boot

I have this placeholder variable in the `application-DEV.properties` file:

```
vm.hostname=${hostname}
```

Apparently this is not being resolved when the app was auto-restarted after VM reboot via `@reboot` command. I got this well known error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder "${hostname}"
```

But when I ran the app as a user on the VM, everything was OK. So I'm guessing at `@reboot` time, value of `${hostname}` was not defined at the VM-level for the Spring Boot app to pick it up?

Comment: so are you specifying the profile through jvm argument?

Comment: @eis - correct!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This jvm arg is required: `-Dhostname=$HOSTNAME`

Everything is working ok after adding this. Arg is required for `@reboot` as well as any crontab as well.